# Autofac register derived types for an interface

Tags: c#, autofac

I have an interface IBase with many derived interfaces IDerived1, IDerived2. I would like to register implementations for the derived interfaces using Autofac.

Given any derived interface, I can write a resolve method for that interface. What I'm wondering is, is there any way that I can avoid enumerating a list of all derived interfaces when building the container?

What I have now is:

```
public static void Register<TDerived>(ContainerBuilder b) where TDerived : IBase {
    b.Register(cc => DerivedFactory.Create<TDerived>(cc.Resolve<SomeDependency>())
     .As<TDerived>()
     .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}

// in my registration method
ContainerBuilder b = ...
MethodInfo genericRegisterDerivedMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("Register", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
List<Type> allDerivedInterfaces = /* query across various assemblies for interfaces which extend IBase */

allDerivedInterfaces.ForEach(t => genericRegisterDerivedMethod 
    .MakeGenericMethod(t)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { b })
);
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
public static void Create<TDerived>(IComponentContext cc) where TDerived : IBase {
    return DerivedFactory.Create<TDerived>(cc.Resolve<SomeDependency>());
}

// in my registration method
ContainerBuilder b = ...
MethodInfo genericResolveDerivedMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

b.RegisterDerivedTypesOf<IBase>((cc, t) => (IBase)genericResolveDerivedMethod
    .MakeGenericMethod(t)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { cc, t })
);
```

This would avoid me needing to know the full list of IDerived interfaces when the applications starts. Is this possible?

Comment: What is `genericRegisterDerivedMethod`? You haven't mentioned generics is your question...

Comment: @nemesv: I've edited the question to provide more detail on MethodInfos.

Comment: If you didn't have to call `DerivedFactory.Create<T>` Autofac could probably help you out here... is there a reason you need to call a static factory instead of using normal constructor injection?

Comment: @default.kramer I'm consuming a static factory method defined in code I can't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using a custom registration source, which can build a registration on the fly for each `IDerived` interface service type that gets requested.